# how to use count and distinct together

Tags: sql

I have a table with names of countries. The country names are duplicated in the table. Eg say there are 8 rows in the table, 5 rows with country `Germany` and 3 with country `UK`. I want to get count the countries in the table (eg. I should get the number 2). But I am unable to come up with the query

I tried `SELECT Country FROM Customers;` but that will give me 8 rows. I tried `SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Customers;` but that gives me 2 rows.  I tried using `count` as `SELECT DISTINCT Count(Country) FROM Customers;` but I get 8 (probably because `DISTINCT` is applied on result set of `SELECT Count(Country) FROM Customers;` How could I get `2`?

Comment: `select count (distinct your_field)...`

Comment: What database are you using?  The exact best answer you get might depend on that.

Comment: thanks folks. Accepted the first correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `distinct` inside count:

```
select count(distinct country)
from customers;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
select count(*)
from (  
  select distinct country
  from customers
  where country is not null
) t;
```

Comment: The `count(distinct country)` query doesn't count null's, but the derived table query does.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . No `where` is necessary.  You can do `count(country)` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

use inside distinct

```
SELECT count( distinct Country) FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct country within count as below:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT country)
FROM customers;
```

You can use distinct country within count and group by country for getting country name as well:

```
SELECT count(1), country
FROM customers
GROUP BY country;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using analytic functions:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*)) cnt
FROM customers
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `limit` however is not standard SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought that the tag were Postgres since I saw your answer.  Anyway, your answer is the way to go, I only gave this as an alternative.